# name mangling in MinGW , plug-in system c++

Tags: c++, mingw, name-mangling

I am learning plugin system in C++ on the windows by using MinGW g++ compiler.
the compiler version is :

C:\SAVVY\src>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0

And I downloaded the source code from here
https://cplusplus.com/articles/48TbqMoL/

then I am trying to figure out the error:
Exception caught: Invalid Plugin DLL: both 'getObj' and 'getName' must be defined.

probably the error line are in main.cpp 59, 60

```
    ObjProc objFunc = (ObjProc) GetProcAddress(mod, "_Z6getObjv");
    NameProc nameFunc = (NameProc) GetProcAddress(mod, "_Z7getNamev");
```

I have looked into the word "name mangling", but I can not find the solution.
Would somebody, please direct me how to the solution.

Comment: IMO, you'd be better advised to give your plugin a C API (rather than C++).  If you're compiling with a C++ compiler, declare all API functions `extern "C"`.  You can read up on the PIMPL idiom.  That would probably be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

That article might be outdated, it's more than 9 years old. The name mangling is not stable and might be change from one to another compiler version. Besides such issue has been reported by a reader 9 years ago and noticed in that article: [loading dll issue](https://cplusplus.com/forum/windows/128653/). Finally that article has been updated with the solution. Go to the chapter **Update - Using the plugin system across different compilers** and see the solution with using `extern "C"`.

Comment: I tried this:
1. download plugin-src.zip and unzip
2. just do "make"
3. move to plugins folder
4. objdump -p test1.dll
5. look at 

[Ordinal/Name Pointer] Table
        [   0] DllMain@12
        [   1] _Z6getObjv
        [   2] _Z7getNameB5cxx11v

6. replace _Z7getNamev to _Z7getNameB5cxx11v in the main.cpp
7. make clean
8. make

Test1:Maths loaded!
Test2:RandNum loaded!
Test3:Filesize loaded!

Hello Everybody! Test1!
        1.79444
This is Test2 Speaking!
        132.914
""
        12288

That's it!